# What are the new "popup windows" in Vim 8.2?

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, popup-menu, popup

The latest version of Vim, 8.2, has a new feature called "popups" or "popup windows". They sound interesting but I'm not quite sure what they're good for. Can you enlighten me...preferably with some examples?

Comment: @MartinTournoij I just noticed the large bounty you've attached. My understanding of bounties was pretty one-dimensional (i.e. it's about attracting additional and/or better answers) but now that I've done some research I think I understand your actual intent (as indicated by your chosen reason and the chosen waiting period) to which I say, "Thanks! That's very generous of you." :)

Comment: Ya, I just wanted to add it to your answer. For some reason you still have to wait 24 hours when you fill in "reward existing answer" ‍♂️ I got way too much reputation anyway just because I was active in the early days; I figured I might as well attach them to some exceptional answers as I come across them.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

*Background: I have a plugin for navigating sections in markup documents and wanted to show the section hierarchy in a popup. I distilled what I learned while implementing this down to the following introduction in hopes of getting others up and running quickly...*

### Overview

Vim 8.2's popup windows allow Vimscript authors and plugin developers to create one or more floating, modal windows that, among other things, can be used for tool tips, notifications/alerts, dialog boxes and transient menus.

### Window and Buffer

Each popup consists of a Vim window and an associated buffer. The window and buffer have a number of unique characteristics including:

- Popup windows will be positioned on top of regular Vim windows.
- Popups can be stacked on each other with stacking order determined by the relative values of their `zindex` attributes.
- The buffer is `'bufhidden'`, is not `'buflisted'` (it won't show up in a buffer listing), and has a `'buftype'` of "popup".
- There is no cursor in a popup. (Oddly, if the cursor in the underlying window is below the popup it will remain visible.)
- The buffer has no swapfile or undo capability and is not editable by normal means but the content can be modified post-creation with `popup_settext()`.
- A popup's initial contents are specified via a parameter to one of the create functions. The content can be in a string or a list of strings. Alternatively, you can pass the number of an existing buffer containing your content. (To create a buffer solely for the popup see `bufadd()`.)
- The window/buffer look and feel is highly customizable.

### Creation

There are six different functions for creating popup windows. That's a lot but five of them are basically wrappers around `popup_create()` that provide "pre-packaged" configurations for particular purposes. Here they all are with brief descriptions taken from `:h popup-functions`:

- `popup_create()` - centered in the screen
- `popup_atcursor()` - just above the cursor position, closes on mouse move
- `popup_beval()` - at pos indicated by v:beval_ variables, closes on mouse move
- `popup_notification()` - show a notification for three seconds
- `popup_dialog()` - centered with padding and border
- `popup_menu()` - prompt for selecting an item from a list

### Customization

Text appearance can be controlled with syntax highlighting or using text properties (another major new feature in Vim 8.2...like syntax highlighting except it sticks to associated text as it moves in the buffer). There are also a number of attributes or "options" that control certain other look-and-feel characteristics. This is a sampling of those options.

- *Placement/Size:* `line`, `col`, `pos` (e.g. "botright"), `resize` (with mouse), `drag` (with mouse), `minwidth`<sup>*</sup>
- *Appearance:* `padding`, `border`, `borderchars`, `highlight` (a la `:hi`), `title`, `mask` (see example below)
- *Behavior:* `time` (until close), `callback` (function), `filter` (input processing)

Option values can be defined on creation of a popup window or afterwards through the `popup_setoptions()` function.

<sub>* It's worth noting that popup window dimensions are, by default, dictated by the contained text. You can override this behavior, within limits, using `minwidth`, `maxwidth`, `minheight`, `maxheight`.</sub>

### Interaction

A popup's lifetime can be controlled several ways including by timer, upon mouse movement or user input or programmatically with `popup_close()`. The nuclear option, `popup_clear()`, will dismiss any and all existing popups.

How a popup processes user input can be controlled with so-called "filters". There are a couple of builtin filters including the "yesno" filter demonstrated in the examples below.

Each popup can have an assigned callback function. When the popup is closed this function is called with the "result". This is most applicable for popups acting as menus. The result, in that case, is usually just the number of the row that the user selected. We'll see this in action, too, below.

### Examples

Finally, we get to the good stuff!

#### Notification

For a time-limited notification popup:

```
call popup_notification("Get the hell out of Dodge!", 
     \ #{ line: 5, col: 10, highlight: 'WildMenu', } )
```

[image]

As noted above this will show for three seconds then close.

#### Menu

Now for a simple menu:

```
func! MenuCB(id, result)
    echo "You chose item #".a:result
endfunc

call popup_menu(['The quick fox...', '...jumped over...', '...the lazy dogs!'], 
     \ #{ title: "Well? Pick one", callback: 'MenuCB', line: 25, col: 40, 
     \ highlight: 'Question', border: [], close: 'click',  padding: [1,1,0,1]} )
```

[image]

Note the `padding` option which I used to put a little space between the menu items and the top and side borders.

Choosing the last row results in...

[image]

#### Yes/No Dialog

In this example we'll use the builtin filter `popup_filter_yesno`. This will wait until the user has clicked a close key (`x` or `<Esc>`) or one of `Y`, `y`, `N`, or `n`. Yes replies cause the callback to be called with result 1. No sends result 0.

```
func! YayOrNay(id, result)
    if a:result | echo "You said 'yay'" | endif
endfunc

call popup_dialog('[y]ay or [n]ay?', #{ filter: 'popup_filter_yesno', callback: 'YayOrNay'})
```

[image]

If I choose `Y` or `y` the message ("You said 'yay'") will show on the status line.

If you specify your own filter function then you can intercept a subset of key presses, handling them in whatever way you choose and pass the rest on to the generic filter, `popup_filter_menu()`. There's an example at `:h popup-examples`.

#### The Base Case

Let's try the primary function, `popup_create()`, with no options...

```
call popup_create(poplist, #{ })
```

`poplist` is a list of strings representing a hierarchical menu, with appropriate numbering and spacing included.

[image]

So by default we get a popup window positioned in the middle of the main window, having no borders or padding and with dimensions determined by the content.

#### The Z-Index and Masking

Finally, let's see the z-index functionality and, for amusement mostly, demonstrate the mask attribute. With 'mask' you can
specify popup coordinates and those sections of the popup will be rendered as transparent. I've yet to think of a practical use for this so I just cut off a couple corners and poked a couple big holes in the thing.

```
call popup_create(poplist, #{ zindex: 20, line: 5, col: 20,
     \ mask: [[1, 10, 1, 3], [-10, -4, 3, 5], [10, 23, -5, -2], [-10, -1, -3, -1]] })
```

[image]

Normally one would expect additional popups to be placed over existing ones but by specifying a lower value for the `zindex` attribute....

```
call popup_create(poplist, #{ zindex: 10, line: 7, col: 25, highlight: 'CursorLine' })
```

...we can make it a pop-under:

[image]

The garish pink? That's the default color for popups in many color schemes. (Completion menu users will likely have seen it before! :P) Override with the new highlight groups `Popup` and `PopupSel`.

### Other Features

Well, I hope that gives you a good sense of what popups are capable of. There are certainly some features I haven't covered or only mentioned briefly including:

- Asynchronous content fill-in
- Popup manipulation functions (e.g. `popup_move()`, `popup_setoptions()`)
- User-defined filters
- Key mappings
- Building a popup from a user-created buffer.
- Running a terminal in a popup window

To learn more about those and everything else popup related visit `:h popup` for a thousand-plus lines of juicy popup goodness.

Comment: That markdown outline jumping thing sounds useful... i’d love to stay posted on its development

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I created it for myself but I can share it if it reaches an appropriate level of stability/usability. Note, though, that I said markUP. Specifically, I use asciidoc(tor) which is similar to but much more powerful than markdown.

Comment: Awesome answer! Good to see so many examples

Comment: I was thinking about making outline in a popup but not sure if it is possible to scroll -- my documents are large :) WIP https://github.com/habamax/vim-do-outline

Comment: @MaximKim Looks like we're working on similar things. Add `scrollbar: 1` to the option map when you call `popup_create` and a scrollbar will be there if the text doesn't fit. I haven't tried them yet because even my largest asciidoctor doc, which would probably render out to 150 printed pages (I should write a book) has "only" 19 top-level sections. I do have a huge monitor and use tall windows, to be fair.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The markup section navigator thingy works nicely with popups. I had to add custom key handler so numbers can be used to select sections (by default you get nothing more than Up/Down or j/k which sucks with 40 or more sections) I'm digging it and use it every day. Probably a while yet until I share it...todo list is still long...but I almost certainly will.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Take it for a spin if you're so inclined... https://github.com/b-layer/musecnav

Comment: Just used this as a primer to build a custom popup for a WIP wiki plugin... greatly helpful (as you said, had to build a custom key-handler—and I couldn't just make it simple, so it's a data-driven menu with custom keys/actions/descriptions that get turned into either popup mappings or normal mode mappings if you don't have popups. woops.).

Comment: @BLayer sorry, by "this" I meant the post! Anyway, here's the wiki plugin https://github.com/benknoble/wiki-md (feedback welcomed, particularly on documentation. it's a bit hard to describe)

Comment: I'm really curious about the text you're using in your example (under the popup window on the image you posted). Is it your own knowledge base or some book about vimscript? :D @BLayer

Comment: @NordineLotfi The example...the image? Which one? Oh, you mean the text under _all_ of the popups in the main buffer? If so, those are my own. About 10 years ago I started writing all my notes, technical and otherwise, in Asciidoc markup. It's addicting and I've written a heck of a lot since then. :) What caught your eye about them?

Comment: Mostly got curious as i like knowledge base/notes of others :D (there tons of that on github where i usually check them out). The fact that it's also about vimscript made me even curious... @BLayer

Comment: @NordineLotfi Well, if I ever make them public (in Github or otherwise) I'll let you know. ;)

Comment: Yet another use for popups: https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/pull/3817

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well done. BTW, my markup navigation popup is finally reaching a level of stability for both Asciidoc and Markdown that'll allow me to share it wider if I decide I want to do that. I expect to update it on GH within a week, time permitting. I had no idea it would be this much of an effort (roughly 1000 real lines of code)...so many nuances, exceptions, alternatives to deal with. For MD I just decided to lean on syntax highlighting to identify headers (not really an option for AD).

Comment: (Not that 1000 LOC is that much but it is compared to what I predicted and given that I only have a little time each week to work on it. :)

Comment: As regards _building a popup from a user-created buffer_, I've used it to provide "soft" wrapping of current line when `nowrap` is set, in [this plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap).

Comment: @BLayer, as regards _I've yet to think of a practical use for this_, [I have found one](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap/issues/17#issue-1597193747)

Comment: @Enlico Yeah, that's a good example!

Comment: Remarkable answer, thanks.