# How to set the scrolloff for the pop up menu?

Tags: scrolling

`setlocal scrolloff=1` changes the scrolloff for the buffer.  I want to change the scrolloff for the popup menu when I press `<C-N>` or `<C-P>` in INSERT mode.  The scrolloff variable has no effect on the popup menu.  Please advise if there is another variable that will affect the popup menu.

Currently, the popup menu scrolloff seem to be set to 3 with a `pumheight=12`.  At a `pumheight=4`, the popup menu scrolloff is set to 1.  I want a scrolloff of 1 with pumheight of 12.

Comment: Instead of scrolloff, why don't you use padding and minheight? :h popup_create-arguments

Comment: I think we are referring to different popups.  `popup_create-arguments` appears to be a new feature of Vim 8.2.  See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/24462/what-are-the-new-popup-windows-in-vim-8-2.  The popup menu or pum, is the menu that shows up when one uses `<C-N>`, `<C-P>`, `<C-X><C-S>`, ... in INSERT mode.  This existed pre-Vim 8.2.  I don't want to create a new pop-up from scratch, since that would require that I reprogram all the existing functionality in Vim again.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I got confused because both features share the same name. I don't think there is a way to set that kind of properties in :h complete-popup